# Using XFoil to generate data for various Mach numbers

Tags: automotive-engineering, aerospace-engineering

I am attempting to use XFoil to generate a list of coefficients of a given airfoil at a range of speeds.

The first issue I faced is that it appears with XFoil, you give it a Reynolds number (which varies by speed) and an Angle of attack, and it outputs the Coefficients of Lift and drag etc.

What I need, however, is to input a range of subsonic mach numbers (or various reynolds numbers) and for it to output the:

- Lift Coefficient
- Drag Coefficient
- Max AOA (Departure)
- Maximum possible Lift Coefficient

How would I go about this using XFoil or any other similar program?

Comment: might also try [CFD online](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/tags/xfoil.html)

Comment: Will do, thanks.